# How to get user current system theme color

Tags: python, tkinter

hi I am working on a python gui project and I find that the color of the frame of my application depends on the user's system theme color. I want my application to have the same color, may I know how can I achieve that? My application is mainly for windows but if theres a way for linux that would be great. I am using tkinter btw.
Or maybe how to get the color from commandline since we have `os.system(command)` ?


Update:
I have tried inputs listed in [widget styling](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm) but none of them work, my system has a theme color of `light blue`

```
from tkinter import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root['bg'] = 'SystemButtonFace'  # white
    root['bg'] = 'SystemBackground'  # black
    root['bg'] = 'SystemButtonText'  # black
    root['bg'] = 'SystemAppWorkspace'  # grey
    root['bg'] = 'SystemActiveBorder'  # grey
    root['bg'] = 'SystemActiveCaption'  # light grey
    root['bg'] = 'SystemInactiveCaption'  # light grey
    root['bg'] = 'SystemButtonShadow'  # darker grey
    root['bg'] = 'SystemButtonHighlight'  # white with a bit grey
    root['bg'] = 'SystemCaptionText'  # black
    root['bg'] = 'SystemDisabledText'  # darker grey
    root['bg'] = 'SystemHighlight'  # light dark blue
    root['bg'] = 'SystemHighlightText'  # white
    root['bg'] = 'SystemInactiveBorder'  # white
    root['bg'] = 'SystemInactiveCaptionText'  # black
    root['bg'] = 'SystemMenu'  # white
    root['bg'] = 'SystemMenuText'  # black
    root['bg'] = 'SystemScrollbar'  # grey
    root['bg'] = 'SystemWindow'  # white
    root['bg'] = 'SystemWindowFrame'  # dark grey
    root['bg'] = 'SystemWindowText'  # black

    root.mainloop()
```

Setting the background to black does not set the frame to black and I can't find a way to get the light blue color
[image: info]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a customized RGB color by yourself.

Use the key `'bg'` to know your background color.

Anyway, if you want to achieve own customizing of a Tkinter frame, you can do  the following:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

print(root['bg']) # Output: SystemButtonFace
root.configure(bg = '#FF0000') # Configuring new color RED
print(root['bg']) # Output: #FF0000

root.mainloop()
```

There is more about the tkinter styling on this page:

[Widget Styling](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112014139id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm)

Look at the paragraph of the Default system colors for Macintosh and Windows.

There are chances that there are no system colors for Linux as it is managed usually by a black command line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it does not get what I want... please see my update

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter cannot change the color of the window border, nor get the color.  You will need to use some other library specific to your window manager to get or change the color.

Comment: Hi thank you for the info, may I know what is the window manager you mentioned? Do you know which library is able to retrieve the color? Thank you so much

Comment: @Kallzvx The window manager is essentially the OS on Windows and OSX, but could be one of several window manages on linux (eg: gnome, kde, etc).  I do not know which one you're using, and I don't know which libraries would do what you want.